# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in [window addSubview:viewcontroller.view]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, exc-bad-access

I have two universal applications... one is giving me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I do this in the app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    ScrollViewController *vc = [[ScrollViewController alloc] init];
    [window addSubview:vc.view]; // EXC_BAD_ACCESS here
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I do exactly the same (same code, same scroll view controller class) in my other application and get no errors... my scroll view loads fine.

This problem is driving me insane. Here is the ScrollViewController Implementation:

```
@implementation ScrollViewController

- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    UIScrollView *s = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self view] bounds]];

    NSArray *a = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"JCEKKeyboard" owner:self options:nil];

    UIView *v = [a objectAtIndex:0];

    [s setContentSize:CGSizeMake(400, 500)];
    [s addSubview:v];
    [[self view] addSubview:s];
}
```

Comment: Show us the code that creates the view, if as you say, it's done in -init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

init shouldn't be creating the view, loadView does that.  Calling the view getter (vc.view) when view is nil will cause loadView to be invoked.

Read the [documentation for loadView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView), you are using it incorrectly.  You should not call super from loadView and you must set the view property in the view controller.  You should not invoke the getter for view [self view] from inside loadView, because the getter calls loadView.  You are supposed to create the view in loadView and set the view property.

Something like this:

```
- (void)loadView {
    NSArray *a = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"JCEKKeyboard" owner:self options:nil];  
    UIView *v = [a objectAtIndex:0]; 

    CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainscreen].applicationFrame;
    UIScrollView *s = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
    [s setContentSize:CGSizeMake(400, 500)];
    [s addSubview:v];

    self.view = s;
}
```

Comment: I changed it to self.view=s as you suggested and got it working, but if i dont call super then the app crashes on launch.

Comment: Do you have a nib for that view built in IB?  If so, you are not supposed to use loadView.  Let the system load the nib and you can add anything you need in viewDidLoad, not in loadView.  Read the Discussion part of the doc for loadView, I provided a link to it in my answer.

Comment: I'm loading the scroll view programmatically using loadView, then adding a sub view to it using loadNibNamed

Answer (score 2):

Remember that when you add subviews i.e. `[someView addSubview:someOtherView]`, you are adding potentially a whole graph of subviews (the subviews of `someOtherView`).  If `someView` is visible it will trigger a render on the new graph of the subview you've added. So if any of the subviews in the new graph are not correctly retained, you can get this error.  You must test the entire view hierarchy you're adding.

Use the following gdb commands in your console:

To test if an individual object is valid

```
po [someView description]
```

To test the subviews of `someView`

```
po [someView subviews]
```

To test individual subviews (for instance the first subview element 0)

```
po [[someView subviews] objectAtIndex:0]
```

Finally to test an *entire view hierarchy* at once

```
po [someView recursiveDescription]
```

These commands, especially `recursiveDescription`, are also very useful for troubleshooting layout issues.